# Manter a tela ligada v4.1.x

Tags: android

Tenho o seguinte código para manter a tela sempre ligada:

```
if (usuario.getTelaLigada()){   
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
}
```

Funciona na versão 4.4 e superiores.
Mas não nas anteriores.

Como faço para manter a tela ligada em todas as versões?

Obrigado!

Comment: Veja isso: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031838/turning-screen-on-off-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma prática muito comum no desenvolvimento Android é utilizar `PowerManager.WakeLock` para fazer tal tarefa. Porém, essa não é a opção ideal e a mais confiável, já que você irá precisar adicionar uma permissão a mais em sua aplicação só para isso.

Além disso, se, acidentalmente você (ou algum outro desenvolvedor de sua equipe) esquecer de desliga-lo, pode drenar a bateria do aparelho do seu usuário.

Para isso, recomendo que você utilize o método `setKeepScreenOn()` dentro da classe `View`:

Caso você esteja criando alguma view via código:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.driver_home, null);
    view.setKeepScreenOn(true);
    setContentView(v);
}
```

Ou, via xml:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">

    ...

</RelativeLayout>
```

OBS: Não importa se a flag `keepScreenOn` esteja no seu layout principal, na raiz ou em outro layout dentro de sua árvore de views, irá funcionar da mesma maneira em qualquer componente em seu `xml`. O único ponto é que a visibilidade desta view precisa estar como `visible`, caso contrário, não irá funcionar!